# AudioPlayer 5.2.1 crashes while setting the DeviceFileSource in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

My code is as follows:

```
Future<void> startPlayer(String filepath) async {
    try {
 // For ex, filepath is getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path+"/file.aac"
      final DeviceFileSource source = DeviceFileSource(filepath); 
     
        await _player?.play(source);
        } catch (e) {
      throw SoundPlayerException(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

But it still throws the **PlatformException(DarwinAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, AVPlayerItem.Status.failed on setSourceUrl, null)**. It works smoothly on Android. Not sure what is the exact issue. the same code was working fine earlier. I tried Flutter_sound plugin as well. it is not able to play the audio file as well.
I have also copied the code from the demo/examples and tried to play the same file as well but no luck with both plugins.

If anyone has an idea, please guide me. I am clueless.